# How to let this sruct to save another coffee type by a user?

Tags: c++, struct

Hey this code is for a coffee machine..I want to add a operator mode for this coffee machine.At the moment i have 7 types of coffee cups.In operator mode i have to write a code to add another couple of coffee types to the existing struct(drink).And operator should have the ability to do that(Any one who check the code).This code is for my 1st sem uni assignment.

```
enter code here
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct coffee {
  string name;
  int itemprice;
  string country;
  int quantity;

};

float remainder, price2, price;
int main() {
      int coffeetype = 1; 
    cout<<"\nPress'1'for buy a coffee\n";
    cout<<"\nPress' 2' for operator mode\n\n";
    int input;
    cin>>input;
    if (input==2)
    {
        cout << "Welcome to operator mode \n";
        cout << "Press '1' for add more coffee powder \n";
        cout << "Press '2' for exit\n";
        int op;
        cin >> op;
        if(op==2){
            return op;
        }
    }
        coffee drink[] = {
      { "Espresso", 120, "Italy", 20 },
      { "Iced coffee", 150, "France", 20 },
      { "Long black", 80, "Austral", 20 },
      { "Americano", 100, "America", 20 },
      { "Latte", 200, "Italy", 20 },
      { "Irishcoffee",130, "Ireland", 20 },
      { "Cappuccino", 180, "Italy", 20 }
    };

        cout << fixed;
        cout << setprecision(2);

   cout<<"Enter the name of coffee";



    while(coffeetype != 8){
    for (int i = 0; i != sizeof(drink)/sizeof(drink[0]); ++i)
        cout<< "\n " << i+1 << ") "<<drink[i].name<<"\t\t"<<drink[i].itemprice<<"\t\t"<<drink[i].country<<"\t\t("<<drink[i].quantity<<") remaining";
```

Comment: Well then you need some kind of *dynamic array*. Exactly how to solve that depends on your assignment/exercise and its requirements.

Comment: Hey could you tell me how to do it with a dynamic array..

Comment: First of all you need to read your assignment thoroughly to see what kind of limitations it sets. Then consult your text-books and class notes. And as a last resort go to your favorite engine and search for e.g. `c++ dynamic array`. If you're still unsure, your teacher, professor or teachers assistant should always be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of fixed array `drink` in your code, use vector. Read about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Your `drink` will be modelled now as:

```
vector<coffee> drink {
    { "Espresso", 120, "Italy", 20 },
    { "Iced coffee", 150, "France", 20 },
    { "Long black", 80, "Austral", 20 },
    { "Americano", 100, "America", 20 },
    { "Latte", 200, "Italy", 20 },
    { "Irishcoffee",130, "Ireland", 20 },
    { "Cappuccino", 180, "Italy", 20 }
};
```

And when user enters `op == 1` in operator mode, you would collect inputs from user and "push_back" (add at end) to that vector.

```
coffee entry;
cin >> entry.country
    >> entry.itemprice
    >> entry.country
    >> entry.quantity;
drink.push_back(entry);
```